# Biblioteca para emissão de notas fiscais eletrônicas

Tags: python, biblioteca

Estou precisando de uma biblioteca em Python para emissão de notas fiscais eletrônicas... Alguém aí tem experiência com alguma?
Vocês saberiam me dizer se preciso adquirir algum certificado com o governo para emissão dessas notas?

Comment: Vê a da daruma...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a [PySPED](https://github.com/aricaldeira/PySPED)

```
### Exemplo ###

from pysped.nfe.manual_401 import *

n = NFe_200()

# Com este método você carrega o xml dentro do Objeto NFe_200 e a partir disto você pode acessar qualquer elemento.
n.set_xml("<chaveNota>.xml")

# Por exemplo assim você acessa o primeiro detalhamento, (det é uma lista) e dentro do detalhamento o produto
n.infNFe.det[0].prod
```

Dá uma olhada [nesse sistema](http://pydoc.net/Python/PySPED/0.1.1/pysped.nfe.manual_300/) para ter uma referência de como emitir sua nf-e e trabalhar com outras funcionalidades que você precise.

Sobre a permissão do governo, acredito que no mínimo você precise da [MEI](http://www.portaldoempreendedor.gov.br/mei-microempreendedor-individual) para emitir nf-e.